# How to apply a partial update to an object using AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

The `$save()` in Angularfire 0.8 is confusing me.

Here's a minimal example - a snippet from my controllers.js file:

```
    .controller('LandingPageController', ['$scope','$firebase', function($scope,$firebase) {
        $scope.addNode = function() {
            var FB = new Firebase('https://protodb.firebaseio.com/testrecords/');
            var fbr = $firebase(FB);
            fbr.$set(1,{firstname: 'James'});
        }
        $scope.addAttribute = function() {
            var FB = new Firebase('https://protodb.firebaseio.com/testrecords/1');
            var fbr = $firebase(FB).$asObject();
            fbr.lastname = "Bond";
            fbr.$save();
        }
        }])
```

When `addNode()` is called, sure enough, a node is created in my firebase:

[image]

But when `addAttribute()` is called, the entire record is replaced, rather than what I expected, which was for the 'lastname' attribute to be added.

[image]

I've no doubt misunderstood the docs. Can anyone help?

Update:

OK, I needed to wait until the object was loaded. It works now, after changing `addAttribute` to:

```
    $scope.addAttribute = function() {
          var FB = new Firebase('https://protodb.firebaseio.com/testrecords/1');
          var fbr = $firebase(FB).$asObject();
          fbr.$loaded().then(function() {
              fbr.lastname = "Bond";
              fbr.$save();
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found out yourself already:

1. a `FirebaseObject` (as returned by `$asObject()`) does not have a `$update` method.
2. when you call `$save()` on a `FirebaseObject` before it is completely loaded, you may end up deleting other properties

To patch existing data you can:

1. Either wait for the entire object to be loaded (as you did in your update to the question)
2. Or call `$firebase.$update` directly

```js
$firebase(FB).$update({ lastname: "Bond" });
```

This last approach has the advantage that you don't pull down the entire object, only to update a single property. Note that this is probably [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) in most cases, but still...

Comment: This doesn't work I'm afraid - fbr is a $FirebaseObject which doesn't have an $update method - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#firebaseobject

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had an array. `$FirebaseObject` does indeed not have an update method, so you'll have to take another approach. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. Interesting that the documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html explicitly suggests you can do it at the object level. See "Saving the Synchronized Object ... We can then update the object and save it back to firebase using the $save() method".

Comment: Spoke too soon. The $FirebaseArray object doesn't have an $update method either. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray

Comment: I copied that from one of my apps, but misread: it indeed uses `$firebase.$update`. So `$firebase.$update` is the way to go: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-basics.