# AngularFire: How to apply partial update (a single field) to an item in $firebaseArray?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm wondering how I can apply a partial update to an item in `$firebaseArray`, and the documentation is confusing with no mention of this. `.$save` seems to clobber the entire item:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/items");
$scope.items = $firebaseArray(ref);
someItem = getItem();
someItem.newField= 'Test';
$scope.items.$save(someItem);
```

This causes the entire item object to be completely overridden, instead of just updating `newField`

I've seen [other discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035526/how-to-apply-a-partial-update-to-an-object-using-angularfire) of how to do this using `$asObject` but I'm still confused how to handle this with items in a `$firebaseArray`

Comment: What does `getItem()` look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I can help here. First, a few things:

- I'm assuming your `getItem()` doesn't use [`.$getRecord()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey) and therefore `someItem` doesn't have an `$id` property. So, the properties of `someItem` get set as the properties of `$scope.items`.
- You can `.$add(someItem)` to `itemsArray` if you want to create a new item.
- You could use `$scope.items.$save(someItem)` if `someItem` has an `$id`.

#### Code

```js
var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/items');
itemsList = $firebaseArray(ref);
$scope.items = itemsList;

$scope.addItemObject = function() {
  var someItem = {};
  someItem.newField = 'test';
  itemsList.$add(someItem);
  console.log('$scope.items is',$scope.items);
}

$scope.updateItem = function() {
  console.log('$scope.items was',$scope.items);
  var id = prompt("Enter $id to update");
  var someItem = itemsList.$getRecord(id);
  var newField = prompt('Enter new value for newField');
  someItem.newField = newField;
  itemsList.$save(someItem).then(function(ref) {
    console.log('$scope.items is now',$scope.items);
  });;
}
```

#### Example

- See this working [PLNKR example](http://plnkr.co/edit/blkh4M4WOJPmcwv6HtJi?p=preview)
- I created ItemsFactory in the PLNKR, which achieves the same result as the code above.

#### Documentation

Take a look at:

- [`$firebaseArray $add()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata)
- [`$firebaseArray $save()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex)
- [`$firebaseArray $getRecord()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was probably it. You're welcome!